# SQL Pivot query with summary data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I just can't get my head around how to do this pivot query.  I have tried several variations but I keep getting errors!

I have this data:

```
ID    OfficerAge    CitizenAge
1       35             21
2       36             33
3       22             18
```

and I can easily get the age groups for each person but I want a matrix:

```
Officer/Citizen:   Under 19   20-29   30-39
Under 19           0          0       0
20-29              1          0       0
30-39              0          1       1
```

I appreciate any assistance in getting the query built correctly!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just build the query using aggregation:

```
select (case when officerage < 19 then 'Under 19'
             when officerage < 30 then '19-29'
             when officerage < 40 then '30-39'
             else 'old!'
        end) as officeragegrp,
       sum(case when citizenage < 19 then 1 else 0 end) as [Under 19],
       sum(case when citizenage >= 19 and citizenage < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [19-29],
       sum(case when citizenage >= 30 and citizenage < 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [30-39],
       sum(case when citizenage > 39 then 1 else 0 end) as [Old!]
from t
group by (case when officerage < 19 then 'Under 19'
               when officerage < 30 then '19-29'
               when officerage < 40 then '30-39'
               else 'old!'
          end)
order by min(officerage);
```

EDIT:

If you need to include even groups that don't exist, then a `left join` helps:

```
select officeragegroupp,
       sum(case when citizenage < 19 then 1 else 0 end) as [Under 19],
       sum(case when citizenage >= 19 and citizenage < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [19-29],
       sum(case when citizenage >= 30 and citizenage < 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [30-39],
       sum(case when citizenage > 39 then 1 else 0 end) as [Old!]
from (select 'Under 19' as officeragegroup union all
      select '19-29' union all
      select '30-39' union all
      select 'old!'
     ) oag left join
     (select t.*,
             (case when officerage < 19 then 'Under 19'
                   when officerage < 30 then '19-29'
                   when officerage < 40 then '30-39'
                   else 'old!'
              end) as officeragegroup
      from t
     ) t
     on t.officeragegroup = oag.officeragegroup
group by oag.officeragegroup
order by min(t.officerage);
```

Comment: Nice!  But doesn't include the age group of [Under 19] with all 0's.  (i mean it would include it if there were values >0, but yeah)